# Where/How do you configure phusion passenger when running nginx?

Tags: configuration, nginx, phusion-passenger

Im running Nginx and Phusion Passenger for my rails app and I want to be able to configure passenger.  All I have seen is how to configure it while running apache which doesn't help me. For example, I want to change the following

PassengerPoolIdleTime 0
RailsFrameworkSpawnerIdleTime 0

Where does this go?  Putting it in my nginx config causes unknown directive errors.

Answer (score 1):

Overlooked the Nginx version of documentation, arrived at the apache version apparently.

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html